# TCP/UDP hybrid connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I'm looking to enhance a WPF app I have that currently receives/broadcasts UDP datagrams within its network with a bridge functionality to share packets with other instances of the app on different subnets.

I essentially want one instance to connect with another and then be broadcast UDP packets while a connection is maintained. To do this, I figure a TCP connection will work at least for the handshake and periodic acks. However, I do not require the TCP overhead for the data itself, which could be transmitted multiple times per second for hours or longer (however long the two are connected).

Given these requirements does it make sense to do a hybrid where the TCP is used for handshaking/acks but data is sent via UDP (I assume the TCP connection can be configured to be kept open indefinitely), or would the additional overhead of sending the datagrams as TCP payloads be negligible? Or should I implement a syn/ack functionality within the UDP transmission? Is there an established standard for this sort of connection?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of how the pipelines are working in this case. If you can't forward the next UDP datagram until the TCP connection receives an ack then your network performance is equal to the slowest of the UDP and TCP connections. In that case I see no advantage to simply using TCP and dispensing with the UDP altogether.

Comment: The purpose of the TCP is really just a method for one side to inquire, "should I keep sending the datagrams you asked for a while back?" and the other to say, "yes, I'm still listening". If a message here and there is missed in the process, it's inconsequential - so ongoing validation of the data itself would be wasted.

Comment: In thinking about this some more, I suppose the easiest way might be just to establish some sort of "request broadcast to this endpoint" UDP message that's effective for n seconds by which time it must be resent or else transmission will cease.

Comment: Why would you use TCP at all?

Comment: Because I need a connection mechanism. So as someone who is pretty inexperienced in network programming, I was soliciting advice on whether it'd be more advisable to add one to a UDP transmission or to incur unnecessary overhead (however much that is, I'd be curious to know) with a protocol that already has one. And I think now the answer is clearly the former.